# How to use phpmailer from sh service framework

Tags: php, frameworks

I am really stuck in email concept. I used sh service framework for past 3 days i am searching all the way to find how email concept works in sh service especially php mailer.

Thanks and help needed

Comment: Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
 and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)

Answer (score 0):

Use this command :

composer require phpmailer/phpmailer

Follow below procedure:

require 'vendor/autoload.php';

$app->get('/contactus',function($app){

```
 $mail = new PHPMailer;
 $mail->isSMTP();   
$mail->Host = 'smtp1.example.com;smtp2.example.com'; 
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->Username = 'user@example.com';
$mail->Password = 'secret';
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls'; 
$mail->Port = 587;         

$mail->setFrom('from@example.com', 'Mailer');
$mail->addAddress('joe@example.net', 'Joe User');     
$mail->addAddress('ellen@example.com');              
$mail->addReplyTo('info@example.com', 'Information');
$mail->addCC('cc@example.com');
$mail->addBCC('bcc@example.com');

$mail->addAttachment('/var/tmp/file.tar.gz');         // Add attachments
$mail->addAttachment('/tmp/image.jpg', 'new.jpg');    // Optional name
$mail->isHTML(true);       // Set email format to HTML

$mail->Subject = 'Here is the subject';
$mail->Body    = 'This is the HTML message body <b>in bold!</b>';

if(!$mail->send()) {
echo 'Message could not be sent.';
echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
echo 'Message has been sent';
}    // Set mailer to
```

});
it is working fine.

Thanks